# Vue.js input value not reflecting value in component data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3

I have the following input:

```
<input :value="inputAmount" @input="handleAmountInput($event)" placeholder="Enter amount..." type="text">
```

I don't want 2-way binding with `inputAmount` because I want to clean the input of non-numeric characters in the `handleAmountInput()` function whenever the user inputs something:

```
handleAmountInput(e) {
    const cleanInput = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.inputAmount = cleanInput;
    console.log(cleanInput);
},
```

The issue is, the input itself doesn't reflect this cleaned up string set to `inputAmount`. If I show `inputAmount` in a separate element or `console.log` it like in the snippet above, it shows up just fine, but binding the value to the input with `:value` doesn't seem to work and shows the full inputted string, including non-numeric characters. What am I doing wrong here and how do I get the input to show the cleaned up string?

Comment: I have a hunch its due to some lifecycle issue. try checking out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue especially the very bottom (next-tick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not yet sure why exactly your code doesn't work as I would expect it to, but the way to fix it is to use both `v-model` and `@input` handler at the same time...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      inputAmount: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleAmountInput(e) {
      this.inputAmount = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      console.log(this.inputAmount);
    },
  },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <input v-model="inputAmount" @input="handleAmountInput($event)" placeholder="Enter amount..." type="text">
  <pre>{{ inputAmount }}</pre>
</div>
```

**Update**

Ok, I now understand the reason why your code does not work. What happens:

0. Value of `inputAmount` is for example `'123'` (reflected in `<input>`)
1. User types `a`
2. Your `@input` handler is called. It receives the value `'123a'`, do it's job creating cleaned value `'123'` and assigns it into `inputAmount`
3. From Vue POV the value of `inputAmount` **did not changed at all** so no re-render is required and `<input>` still shows `'123a'` even tho `inputAmount` has a value of `'123'`

So another way of fixing your code is just to assign some value `<input>` can never produce into `inputAmount` 1st just to trigger the update (demo below)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      inputAmount: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleAmountInput(e) {
      this.inputAmount = null
      this.inputAmount = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      console.log(this.inputAmount);
    },
  },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <input :value="inputAmount" @input="handleAmountInput($event)" placeholder="Enter amount..." type="text">
  <pre>{{ inputAmount }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, you're completely right. I totally missed the fact that `inputAmount` doesn't get mutated at all if the user enters letters. Setting it to `null` at the beginning of the function does the job perfectly, thank you.

Edit: now that I think about it a bit more, I'm still confused as to why `inputAmount` shows up correctly when called elsewhere in the template, e.g. <p>{{inputAmount}}</p>, but the trick still works so I'll just go with it.

Comment: BTW you can use to limit input to just numbers: `<input v-model.number="age" type="number" />`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **@change** event

```
<input :value="message" @change="getInput($event)" placeholder="edit me" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **computed** getter setter instead, [Link](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) :

example :

```
computed: {
    inputAmount: {
        get(){
            //perform your logic
            return 'value'            
        },
        set(newValue){
            this.value= newValue;
        }

    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `v-model="inputAmount"`?  please see: https://cn.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html
then you can just edit like `this.inputAmount= this.inputAmount.replace(/\D/g, '');`